# Remap using CapsLock, with light diode and without capitalizing

Tags: autohotkey

I want to remap some keys (`Left`, `Right`, `Up`, `Down`, `Home`, `End`) while `CapsLock` is pressed. There are two indispensable conditions. The first: `CapsLock`'s light should be toggled on and off. And the second: the pressed letters should not be <s>ALL CAPS</s> all caps.

For example, I can use the code below. The problem is, that all pressed letters will be capitalized. `a` become `A`, `b` become `B` and so on. This is bad.

```
~CapsLock::
Suspend, Toggle
Return

Left::
SendInput {Up}
Return
```

Also I can remove the tilda (see first line):

```
CapsLock::
Suspend, Toggle
Return

Left::
SendInput {Up}
Return
```

But the problem is, that light on the keyboard will not be toggled. It will be always off. This is also bad.

What's the way to do it?

Comment: How to control the Keyboad LEDs: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/9587-keyboard-led-control-capslocknumlockscrolllock-lights/

Comment: Thanks. As I understand from your link, that is possible only with some large and hacky script. No way to do it short and easy way?

Comment: have you seen https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetNumScrollCapsLockState.htm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires some DLL calls, and yes it is hacky. It's a wonder that it's even possible at all. 
This is pretty much as short as you could get:

```
Kbd := 0 ;if that doesn't work try 2 instead

virtualCapslockState := False
KeyboardLED(4,"off",Kbd)

Capslock::
    virtualCapslockState := !virtualCapslockState
    If (virtualCapslockState)
        KeyboardLED(4,"on",Kbd)
    Else
        KeyboardLED(4,"off",Kbd)
Return

#If virtualCapslockState
    Left::Up
    Right::Down
    Up::Left
    Down::Right
    Home::End
    End::Home
#If

/*

    Keyboard LED control for AutoHotkey_L
        http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=468000#468000

    KeyboardLED(LEDvalue, "Cmd", Kbd)
        LEDvalue  - ScrollLock=1, NumLock=2, CapsLock=4
        Cmd       - on/off/switch
        Kbd       - index of keyboard (probably 0 or 2)

*/
KeyboardLED(LEDvalue, Cmd, Kbd=0) {
    SetUnicodeStr(fn,"\Device\KeyBoardClass" Kbd)
    h_device := NtCreateFile(fn,0+0x00000100+0x00000080+0x00100000,1,1,0x00000040+0x00000020,0)
    If (Cmd = "switch")  ;switches every LED according to LEDvalue
        KeyLED:= LEDvalue
    If (Cmd = "on")  ;forces all choosen LED's to ON (LEDvalue= 0 ->LED's according to keystate)
        KeyLED:= LEDvalue | (GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T") + 2*GetKeyState("NumLock", "T") + 4*GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T"))
    If (Cmd = "off") { ;forces all choosen LED's to OFF (LEDvalue= 0 ->LED's according to keystate)
        LEDvalue := LEDvalue ^ 7
        KeyLED := LEDvalue & (GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T") + 2*GetKeyState("NumLock", "T") + 4*GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T"))
    }
    success := DllCall( "DeviceIoControl" ,  "ptr", h_device , "uint", CTL_CODE( 0x0000000b , 2 , 0 , 0  ) , "int*", KeyLED << 16 , "uint", 4 ,  "ptr", 0 , "uint", 0 ,  "ptr*", output_actual ,  "ptr", 0 )
    NtCloseFile(h_device)
    return success
}
CTL_CODE( p_device_type, p_function, p_method, p_access ) {
    return, ( p_device_type << 16 ) | ( p_access << 14 ) | ( p_function << 2 ) | p_method
}
NtCreateFile(ByRef wfilename,desiredaccess,sharemode,createdist,flags,fattribs) {
    VarSetCapacity(objattrib,6*A_PtrSize,0)
    VarSetCapacity(io,2*A_PtrSize,0)
    VarSetCapacity(pus,2*A_PtrSize)
    DllCall("ntdll\RtlInitUnicodeString","ptr",&pus,"ptr",&wfilename)
    NumPut(6*A_PtrSize,objattrib,0)
    NumPut(&pus,objattrib,2*A_PtrSize)
    status:=DllCall("ntdll\ZwCreateFile","ptr*",fh,"UInt",desiredaccess,"ptr",&objattrib ,"ptr",&io,"ptr",0,"UInt",fattribs,"UInt",sharemode,"UInt",createdist ,"UInt",flags,"ptr",0,"UInt",0, "UInt")
    return % fh
}
NtCloseFile(handle) {
    return DllCall("ntdll\ZwClose","ptr",handle)
}
SetUnicodeStr(ByRef out, str_) {
    VarSetCapacity(out,2*StrPut(str_,"utf-16"))
    StrPut(str_,&out,"utf-16")
}
```

You could also remove the comment. And it would be possible to save maybe 10 more lines by replacing the if statements with ternary operators and by putting the small functions content to where it's needed directly..

Comment: Thanks for the code and explanation about the task's complexity, I will mark it as answer. However, I should notice (for other people who will try this code) that keyboard light doesn't work for me. I think, that is some software vs. hardware issue - the kind of problems that are very hard to resolve.

Comment: It should work. Try to change the "Kbd" variable in the first line to a different number. Maybe your keyboard is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6... Also try to compile the script and run the exe as admin.